# How can I show that these two definitions of the pseudospectrum are equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, perturbation-theory

The following is from problem 26.1 in [Trefethen and Bau](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot50/):

> Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ with spectrum
>   $\Lambda(A)\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and $\epsilon>0$, define the 2-norm
>   *$\epsilon$-pseudospectrum* of $A$, $A_\epsilon(A)$, to be the set of numbers $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying any of the following conditions:
>
> - (i) $z$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\delta A$ for some $\delta A$ with $||\delta A||_2\leq\epsilon$;
> - (ii) there exists a vector $u\in\mathbb{C}^m$ with $||(A-zI)u||_2\leq\epsilon$ and $||u||_2=1$;
> - (iii) $\sigma_m(zI-A)\leq\epsilon$;
> - (iv) $||(zI-A)^{-1}||_2\geq\epsilon^{-1}$.
>
> Prove that conditions (i)–(iv) are equivalent.

**Edit:**
I now have the professor's solution, but I still can't make much sense of it, although it looks like I was somewhat on the right track before. Here are the troubling bits:

> Since $||(zI-A)^{-1}||_2\geq\epsilon^{-1}$, there is a vector $v$ with $||v||_2=1$ such that if $w=(zI-A)^{-1}v$, then $||w||_2\geq\epsilon^{-1}$.

So far so good.

> Multiplying each side by $zI-A$, we have $(zI-A)w=v$. It follows that
>   \begin{equation}
> \bigg(zI-A-\frac{vw^*}{w^*w}\bigg)w=0\,,
> \end{equation}

I can't make the "it follows" leap here. How is the fraction constructed?

> so $z$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A+\delta$, where $\delta A=(vw^*)/(w^*w)$.

If $z$ is such an eigenvalue, then by the above equation $w$ must be an eigenvector. How do we know that about $w$?

Comment: Can I have the professor's solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is done is multiplying by 1 in disguise, followed by some rebracketing of the matrices:
$$ v = v \frac{w^*w}{w^*w} = \frac{v(w^*w)}{w^*w}=\frac{(vw^*)w}{w^*w}$$
From here we note that $vw^*$ is indeed a square matrix, and thus so is $\frac{vw^*}{w^*w}$. Make the definition $\delta   A:= \frac{vw^*}{w^*w}$. Then note that 
we can use this to rewrite $(zI - A) w = v$ as $$(zI - (A+\delta A) ) w = 0$$
this is the equation that 'followed'.

Comment: Still a bit shaky on why $z$ is an eigenvalue. How do we know that $w$ is an eigenvector?

Comment: if $(  I - )=0 $ and $≠0$ then  is an eigenvalue of  with eigenvector .

Comment: Hm. How did I get all the way to grad school without the happy chicken-shit notation? (Or, for that matter, without being able to apply a simple definition?) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. We've all (=: I've)  been there.