# Showing two definitions of the pseudospectrum are equivalent 2

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I am piggybacking off of [How can I show that these two definitions of the pseudospectrum are equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556302/376619).

> Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ with spectrum
>   $\Lambda(A)\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and $\epsilon>0$, define the 2-norm
>   *$\epsilon$-pseudospectrum* of $A$, $A_\epsilon(A)$, to be the set of numbers $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying any of the following conditions:
>
> - (i) $z$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\delta A$ for some $\delta A$ with $||\delta A||_2\leq\epsilon$;
> - (ii) there exists a vector $u\in\mathbb{C}^m$ with $||(A-zI)u||_2\leq\epsilon$ and $||u||_2=1$;
> - (iii) $\sigma_m(zI-A)\leq\epsilon$; $\sigma_m$ is smallest singular value of $zI-A$.
> - (iv) $||(zI-A)^{-1}||_2\geq\epsilon^{-1}$.
>
> Prove that conditions (i)–(iv) are equivalent.

I am trying to show how (ii) implies (iii).

I know $||(A-zI)u||_2\leq ||A-zI||_2 \cdot||u||_2 = ||A-zI||_2 = \sigma_n$, where $\sigma_n$ is the largest singular value, so that's of no use. Not to mention, the "direction" of the inequality is opposite to what I need it to be.

All other proofs (e.g. [here](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/pseudospectra/thms/thm1.pdf)) that I have seen have (i)->(ii)->(iv)->(i) and (i)<->(iii) specialized for the 2-norm. I'm curious about the specific implication of (ii)->(iii).

Any hints?